# Check if span contains value but value is after another nestled span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Trying to check if `span` `.woocommerce-Price-amount` contains 19.76. I don't think it's working since there is `<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>`  before the value I'm trying to target.

How can I ignore the currencySymbol span?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".ivpa_term").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".woocommerce-Price-amount").each(function() {
        var inner = $(this).text();
        if (!isNaN(inner) && 19.75 < inner && inner <= 19.76) {
          console.log("Exists!");
        }
      });
    }, 0001);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="quantity">2 × 
  <del>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span> 21.95
    </span>
  </del>
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>19.76
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no regex expert but you could try this if you just want to remove the dollar and get the digits

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

$( ".ivpa_term" ).click(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {

  $(".woocommerce-Price-amount").each(function () {
        var inner = $(this).text();
        var numb = inner.match(/\d+\.+\d+/g); //CHECK FOR NUMBERS AND DECIMALS
        numb = numb.join(""); 
        if (!isNaN(numb) && 19.75 < numb && numb <= 19.76){
                            console.log("Exists!");
        }
        });
                }, 0001);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For a specific value you can use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```js
var res= $(".woocommerce-Price-amount:contains(19.76)").css('color', 'red');
if(res.length){
   console.log('Exists');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="quantity">2 × <del>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>21.95</span>
</del> 
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>19.76</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach that value in multiple ways, one of them could be

```
 var textNode = Array.from(this.childNodes).filter(el => el.nodeType == 3 && Number(el.nodeValue) > 0 );
 var inner = $(textNode[0]).text().trim();
```

**Explanation**

- **Get** all the `childNodes` of element `.woocommerce-Price-amount`
- **Filter** *textnodes* whose *numerical value is greater than 0*

**Demo**

```js
      $(".woocommerce-Price-amount").each(function() {
        var textNode = Array.from(this.childNodes).filter(el => el.nodeType == 3 && Number(el.nodeValue) > 0 );
        //console.log(textNode);
        var inner = $(textNode[0]).text().trim();
        console.log(inner);
        if (!isNaN(inner) && 19.75 < inner && inner <= 19.76) {
          console.log("Exists!");
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="quantity">2 × 
 <del>
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
     <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span> 21.95
</span>
</del>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>19.76</span><span class="my-price"></span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the currency symbol first and cast the remaining content as float with `parseFloat()`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".woocommerce-Price-amount").each(function() {
    var inner = parseFloat($(this).text().replace("$", ""));
    if (!isNaN(inner) && 19.75 < inner && inner <= 19.76) {
      console.log("Exists!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="quantity">2 × 
  <del>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span> 21.95
    </span>
  </del>
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>19.76
    </span>
  <span class="my-price"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the code,

```
var inner = $(this).text();
```

with

```
var inner = $(this).contents().eq(2).text();
```

will works for you.